# git post receive hooks run remote server shell script error expecting keyword_do

Tags: git, shell, githooks

under following post receive hook i do get error after i push to the repository,  `remote: hooks/post-receive:: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('`

post receive script as following,

`#!bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref \
do
   ssh user1@ip -pPassword\ 'path/to/the/shell.sh'
end`

in this case my remote server paswd include `\` , i have tried as follows

`#!bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref do
   ssh user1@ip -pPassword\ 'path/to/the/shell.sh'
end`

`#!bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref \
do
   (ssh user1@ip -pPassword\ 'path/to/the/shell.sh');
end`

Comment: Test your post-receive script manually by running it yourself. Give it sample input if needed, although with this kind of syntax error, you'll normally get the syntax error before it attempts to read anything.

Comment: @Sadzone That's almost certainly an error mesage from your `shell.sh` so you should show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

For the `while` loop in bash, you can either:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref;do
    echo $read $oldrev $newrev $ref
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    echo $read $oldrev $newrev $ref
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev rev;do echo $read $oldrev $newrev $ref;done
```

I'm not sure if the `ssh` part is right, but I don't think the `\` is necessary.

Comment: none of these didn't work for my case scenario, i do get the same error including `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if the ssh part is right

Actually, ssh might work but be part of the issue:

- check that `ssh -T user1@ip -pPassword` work when executed from the  server where the post-receive hook is
- check that is does work *silently*, meaning the user1 `.bashrc` or `.profile` does not echo a bunch of strings, which might then interfer with the hook execution.